# Webpack - multiple entrypoints, require bundles between them

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler, rollup

I have a webpack config with multiple entrypoints that looks more or less like this:

```
const config = {
    entry: {
        'components/index': './src/components',
        'helpers/index': './src/helpers',
    },
}

module.exports = config;
```

This produces two bundle files: `components/index.js` and `helpers/index.js`. That's fine, but the problem is that `components/index.js` contains the whole code from the `helpers`... This is because components are importing a helper functions.

Example:

- `src/helpers` exports function called `foo`.
- `src/components` imports `foo` function from helpers.

Now, in the `components/index.js` bundle I see that the `foo` function is declared. Is there a way to tell webpack that it should use `require()` function instead and import this `foo` function?

So The output for `component/index.js` would look something like this:

```
var foo = require('../helpers/index.js')
/* rest of the code */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to rollup.js and it seems to work like this by default, without any additional configuration:

```
// rollup.config.js

export default {
    input: {
        'components/index': './src/components',
        'helpers/index': './src/helpers',
    },
    output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        format: 'esm',
    },
};
```